# How do I get AppCenter to stop trying to download/install Thunderbird?

Tags: appcenter, macbook, release-hera, thunderbird

How do I get AppCenter to stop trying to download/install Thunderbird?
I just installed elementary 5.1 using VMWare Fusion 11.5.1 on a Macbook Pro running Mojave 10.14.6 I went to AppCenter to download/install Thunderbird. After selecting Thunderbird, AppCenter now says waiting for authentication but there is no authentication screen. AppCenter is showing a spinning icon next to the search window.

Answer (score 0):

Try install Thunderbird with command line

```
sudo apt install thunderbird
```

maybe that will fix your problem

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!